# excessive ad calls from Google AdMob

Tags: admob, ads

I'm using the Google Mobile Ads SDK to get display ads in an iOS app. When the app loads, I make three calls to grab three display ads. But sometimes, (not always!), when I look at the traffic in Charles, I see multiple, excessive ad calls being made.

The call is similar to:

```
GADBannerView 
- (void)loadRequest:(GADRequest *)request;
```

In Charles, I'm looking for calls to:

`http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net:80`

The behaviour seems completely random, in that one day everything will be working fine (a 1-to-1 correspondence between the Xcode ad calling method and calls seen in Charles), and next day there will be many more calls seen in Charles than can be accounted for.

Is this expected? Can the SDK make calls on its own behalf, under certain conditions?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit older, but in case others run into this...

Be careful adjusting the `frame` of the ad view. We found this comment tucked away in an AdMob sdk that implies using it to change the size of the view (instead of adjusting the view's frame).

File:
`Add-ons/DoubleClick/DFPBannerView.h`

Snippet:

`/// Use this function to resize the banner view without launching a new ad request.
- (void)resize:(GADAdSize)size;`

Another comment that alludes to the creation of ad requests without an explicit call to loadRequest is located in GADBannerView.h, lines 60-65:

```
// Required to set this banner view to a proper size. Never create your own
// GADAdSize directly. Use one of the predefined standard ad sizes
// (such as kGADAdSizeBanner), or create one using the GADAdSizeFromCGSize
// method. If not using mediation, then changing the adSize after an ad has
// been shown will cause a new request (for an ad of the new size) to be sent.
// If using mediation, then a new request may not be sent.
```

After performing some experiments with the banner view, it seems that any call to set the view's frame (even just for an X/Y positional update, not a width/height modification) may cause these automatic requests to fire. This may also apply to any resizing that occurs during device rotation.

UPDATE:

I was even having this trouble when using Auto Layout, something autolayout was doing was triggering a separate ad request (not always but sometimes). I fixed this by sticking the ad view inside a container view (which then has the autolayout)... Bit messy, but appears to be working so far.

Hope this helps.